# Root path in Magento instead of hard link

Tags: php, magento, footer

I was wondering if there was any way I can link to a page in magento using the root path instead of the hard link. For example, instead of using http://dev.southlandautomation.com/index.php/t-automationrepair.aspx/?___store=default, is there any way I can get magento to link to this page without using the url.

Comment: Where you want to fetch magento site base url ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I want it to link to the page without using the long hard link for seo purposes.

Comment: yes! I currently have the links to the footer in the footer section of the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch Store URL like in the following way:

```
{{store url=""}}
```

So you can add link like both way

```
{{store url="t-automationrepair.aspx"}}
{{store url=""}}t-automationrepair.aspx
```

Comment: so for the example above I would do {{store url="t-automationrepair.aspx"}}?

Comment: Also would I still us an <a href> tag?

Comment: I have updated the answer. you need to use anchor tag

Comment: So I did <a href="{{store url="t-automationrepair.aspx"}}
"> Repairs </a> and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in CMS Block or page, this should give you source

```
Get Url in cms pages or static blocks

1. Get Base Url :

{{store url=""}}   //eg. <a href="{{store url=''}}"

2. Get Skin Url :

{{skin url='images/imagename.jpg'}}

3. Get Media Url :

{{media url='/imagename.jpg'}}

4. Get Store Url :

{{store url='mypage.html'}}
```

[Reference & More info](http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento-get-base-url-skin-url-media-url-js-url-store-url-and-current-url.html)